# How can I make an tab change it's title when it's active/inactive?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, title

I noticed Mellow Mushroom's website tabs change depending on if it is active or not. I'd like to be able to reproduce this on my personal site.

Here's a video in case you don't know what I mean ---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/axLH4.jpg

Will I need to do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

It's really just two steps. Detect if the browser window is active. That question was asked and answered here: [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active). Then you can just set the document.title property.